# How do you securely serve a file in golang

Tags: go, web-applications

I'm new to developing web applications. I'm working with golang and would like to serve user uploaded files securely, such as allowing them to view their own files only.

Now I have saved those files to a local file system with random names. If I serve the entire directory, malicious users may view other users files. This sounds like a common use case, I wonder what's the best approach to deal with it?

Comment: Instead of serving them raw from the webserver directly, just add a verification layer on the route that a user asks to see one of his files.

Comment: you can use `http.ServeFile()` to serve a file. With some controller logic of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question in pretty vague and architectural decisions must be made to optimize data access and secure the files.

However, here is a simple solution that might serve your use-case.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "mime"
    "net/http"
    "path/filepath"
)

//UserFilesMap is the map that contains
var UserFilesMap map[string]FilePermission

type FilePermission map[string]struct{}

//FileServer is the function that serves files
func FileServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //get the file path the user wants to access
    filename := r.URL.Path[9:]
    var uname, pass string
    var ok bool
    if uname, pass, ok = r.BasicAuth(); !ok {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }

    if !(uname == "user" && pass == "1234") {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }

    //Checking if user has permission to the file
    if _, ok := UserFilesMap[uname][filename]; !ok {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", mime.TypeByExtension(filepath.Ext(filename)))
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "files/"+filename)
}

func main() {
    UserFilesMap = make(map[string]FilePermission)
    // UserFilesMap["user"] = FilePermission{"xyz.txt": struct{}{}}
    UserFilesMap["user"] = FilePermission{"abc.txt": struct{}{}}
    http.HandleFunc("/getFile/", FileServer)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in ListenAndServe")
    }
}
```

Here, I used a map to store the permissions of files. I would suggest you go for a SQL table instead.

Comment: how do you strip prefix in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If ur filenames are random and long enough and use a secure random generator this is already secure (unless directory-listing is enabled) with some limits though.

https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/

One user will have access to the file only if he has the url with the random name. The limitation is though that the URL will be saved in the browser history, if someone else finds it he will also have access to it.